# how to fix javascript not included in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
function setFormMessage(formElement, type, message) {
    const messageElement = formElement.querySelector(".form__message");

    messageElement.textContent = message;
    messageElement.classList.remove("form__message--success", "form__message--error");
    messageElement.classList.add(`form__message--${type}`);
}

function setInputError(inputElement, message) {
    inputElement.classList.add("form__input--error");
    inputElement.parentElement.querySelector(".form__input--error-message").textContent = message;
}

function clearInputError(inputElement) {
    inputElement.classList.remove("form__input--error")
    inputElement.parentElement.querySelector(".form__input--error-message").textContent = "";
}

/* Weg?*/
setFormMessage(loginForm, "success", "You're logged in!");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login");
    const createAccount = document.querySelector("#createAccount");

    document.querySelector("#linkCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.classList.add("form-hidden");
        createAccountForm.classList.remove("form-hidden");
    });

    document.querySelector("#linkLogin").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.classList.remove("form-hidden");
        createAccountForm.classList.add("form-hidden");
    });

    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Perform your AJAX/Fetch login

        setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "Username/password is invalid")
    });

    document.querySelectorAll(".form__input").forEach(inputElement => {
        inputElement.addEventListener("blur", e => {
            if (e.target.id == "signupUsername" && e.target.value.length > 0 && e.target.value.length < 10) {
                setInputError(inputElement, "Username must be at least 10 characters in length");
            }
        });

        inputElement.addEventListener("input", e => {
            clearInputError(inputElement);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/*Hier begint de css van de hele signup pagina*/

body {
    background-color: #212329;

    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  p {
    color: white;
  }
  a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
 
  input {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  input::placeholder {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
/*Hier begint de css van de signup en login*/

  .container {
      width: 400px;
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 1rem;
      padding: 2rem;
      box-shadow: rgb(28, 30, 31) 0px 0px 40px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: rgb(24, 26, 27);
  }

  .container,
  .form__input,
  .form__button {
      font: 500 1rem 'Arial', sans-serif;
  }

  .form--hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .form > *:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
  }

  
  .form > *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form__title {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.form__message {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form__message--success {
    color: #04AA6D;
}

.form__message--error {
    color: #F9423D;
}

.form__input-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form__input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #04AA6D;
  outline: none;
  background: #222426;
  transition: background 0.2s, bordercolor 0.2s;
}

.form__input:focus {
  border-color: #337AF1;
  background: #222426;
}

.form__input-error {
  color: #F9423D;
  border-color: #F9423D;
}

.form__input-error-message {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #F9423D;
}

.form__button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #04AA6D;
}

.form__button:hover {
  background-color: #337AF1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.form__button:active {
  transform: scale (0.98);
}

.form__text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.form__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form__link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #337AF1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">
<script src="js/signup.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img\icon.png">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form" id="login">
<h1 class="form__title">Login</h1>
<div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username or E-mail">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="password" class="form__input form__input--error" autofocus placeholder="Password">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<button class="form__button" type="submit">Login</button>
<p class="form__text">
    <a href="#" class="form__link">Forgot your password?</a>
</p>
<p class="form__text">
    <a class="form__link" href="#" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
</p>
</form>

<form class="form form--hidden" id="createAccount">
<h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1>
<div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="text" id="signupUsername" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="E-mail">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="password" class="form__input form__input--error" autofocus placeholder="Password">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<div class="form__input-group">
<input type="password" class="form__input form__input--error" autofocus placeholder="Confirm password">
<div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
</div>
<button class="form__button" type="submit">Sign up</button>
<p class="form__text">
    <a class="form__link" href="#" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
</p>




</form>
</div>
</body>




</html>
```

My javascript doesnt work. It's like it isn't even included in my php file. Does anyone know how to fix this? If i click create account it should give me another form but it doesn't. Please anyone help me fix this problem. I need this to work to be able to continue with my project.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: try adding a `alert('i am here')` in the top most of your js file and see if there is an alert in the browser.

Comment: In the stylesheet links you should use forward slash, not backslash.

Comment: @NadirAbbas the alert is not working either

Comment: @Barmar still not working

Comment: It wasn't intended to fix it, that's an unrelated issue.

Comment: What about the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: loginForm is not defined` you have in the console

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP? I can't see any PHP code. Is the HTML the code in the PHP file or is this the generated code? What do you get when you try to open the path `js/main.js` in your browser?

Comment: @jabaa i only see the html and css in my browser and no error.

Comment: @CedricCholley When i tried to ask this question i did got this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: loginForm is not defined" what do i have to do to fix it.

Comment: You could call `setFormMessage` after `DOMContentLoaded` has been dispatched

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
/* Weg?*/
setFormMessage(loginForm, "success", "You're logged in!");
```

from where it is now.

Instead put it where you have

```
//Perform your AJAX/Fetch login
```

and implement that login to show the success message on success and the error message in the other case depending on the response of that AJAX call.

There might be other errors, some already pointed out in the comments like e.g.

```
href="css\reset.css"
```

is not a correct path.

Comment: like this?     loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Perform your AJAX/Fetch login
        setFormMessage(loginForm, "success", "You're logged in!");
        setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "Username/password is invalid")
    });

Comment: Well, that alone will not check if a login was successful. From what I make of the comment (which sounds a bit like a homework todo) you will have to make a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to some script that checks the given credentials ...

Comment: i haven't made a database yet. I'm just trying to make my signup complete

Comment: Sure, but the ajax request would be the next step imo. Btw you wouldn't necessarily need a "database" (as in RDBMS) to check credentials, a json file _in a save place_ would also do, or an Active Directory server or anything between :)

Comment: thanks you have any tips or links where i can get started with it because i've never done that before.

Comment: Sorry, I got your last comment totally wrong: I'd recommend to thoroughly learn the basics and then get creative yourself. That's how I did it and am really happy with. MDN (linked above) is a _very_ good resource, php.net another. If you follow tutorials (there are lots of good ones) always be critical. Have fun coding!

Comment: of what do i exactly have to learn to basics of? php? json? RDBMS?